# Why does the while loop not work for this link-list program?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

Can you please help me to understand why the while loop does not work in the following code:

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     typedef struct node_type{
                int data;
                struct node_type *next;
    }node;

    typedef node *list;
    list head;

    void main()
    {
            list temp,new;
            head=NULL;
            int n;
            char ch;
            temp=(list) malloc(sizeof(node));
            printf("\nGive data: ");
            scanf("%d",&temp->data);
            head=temp;
            printf("\n");
            printf("Enter Data? (y/n): ");
            scanf("%c",&ch);while(getchar()!='\n');
            while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
            {
                    new=(list) malloc(sizeof(node));
                    printf("Give data: ");
                    scanf("%d",&new->data);while(getchar()!='\n');
                    temp->next=new;
                    temp=new;
                    printf("\nEnter more data(y/n): ");
                    scanf("%c",&ch);while(getchar()!='\n');
            }
            temp->next=NULL;
            traverse(head);
}
```

**Output is as follows:**
Give data: 2

Enter more data(y/n): y

2

**and the program terminates here.**

Comment: Are lines like `scanf("%c",&ch);while(getchar()!='\n');` to confuse the enemy?

Comment: The `Enter` key you pressed to end the input for the value `2` is also put into the input buffer, as a newline `'\n'`. This is read by the next `scanf` call. If you [learned how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it would have been extremely obvious. And now when you know what the problem is, you can more easily search for it and for solutions (which is much more simple than you seem to think).

Comment: @Eugene Sh. it basically works like fflush(stdin) id do not prefer fflush(stdin) because it is not preferred as a good technique in some books and may invoke improper actions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this piece of code starts to work when i use a do-while loop instead of the while loop

Comment: Please describe the symptoms of "the while loop does not work", maybe by comparing what happens to what you expect/desire to happen.

Comment: @S.Sharma Except that `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Hint: Try `scanf(" %c", &ch);` instead. Note the leading space. Now go and search for *why* it helps.

Comment: @Yunnosch well I want the while loop to invoke a **Give Data: ** to the user till the user enters 'n' in **Enter more data(y/n): **

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well i now get the problem. Thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake. Because i added a space in the printf("Enter more data(y/n): "); and the space screws it up i guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Don't Need to use `while(getchar()!='\n');` everywhere before `scanf()`. This has lead to termination of your program. You could use `scanf("\n%c", &ch);` instead.Also it is recommended to write `new->next = NULL;` after `new = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));`.
Additionally you miss `traverse()` function.

Try this modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node_type
{
        int data;
        struct node_type *next;
} node;

typedef node *list;
list head;

void traverse(node *head) // This is simple traverse function just to demonstrate code.
{
        while (head != NULL)
        {
                printf("%d  ", head->data);
                head = head->next;
        }
}
void main()
{
        list temp, new;
        head = NULL;
        int n;
        char ch;
        temp = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = NULL;
        printf("\nGive data: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);
        head = temp;
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter Data? (y/n): ");
        scanf("\n%c", &ch);
        while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
        {
                new = (list)malloc(sizeof(node));
                new->next = NULL;
                printf("Give data: ");
                scanf("%d", &new->data);
                new->next = NULL;
                temp->next = new;
                temp = new;
                printf("\nEnter more data(y/n): ");
                scanf("\n%c", &ch);
        }
        temp->next = NULL;
        traverse(head);
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Give data: 2

Enter Data? (y/n): y
Give data: 22

Enter more data(y/n): y
Give data: 32

Enter more data(y/n): n

 List is :  2  22  32
```